# how to find Dynamics AX POS errform when it occurs while launching the program

Tags: axapta

I change the configuration file.When I start POS.There should be an errform.And I need to verify it .So how to find errform with specific content?

Answer (score 0):

As for much of POS errors, you have to go to the windows application event log in order to get detailed informations.